# Make linear master branch git

Tags: git, svn, svn2git

I have imported my SVN repository into new git bare repository.

My tags are converted in git tags but i have this git road lines : 
[image]

Is there a method to bring everything back to a single line in the master ?

Like this :

[image]

(I am beginner with git)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is to move the tags to the correct commits (their parent commit). You can do this manually, one by one, using the command:

```
git tag -f v2.8.0 v2.8.0~1
```

Replace `v2.8.0` with the name of each tag.

If there are a lot of tags to move you can use `git tag -l > tags.txt` to produce their list and save it into the `tags.txt` file. Open the file in a text editor and remove the tags that you don't want to modify (if the image posted in the question displays the current history line, only `v2.8.2` and `v2.8.3` are properly placed; remove them from the file). Save the file then run:

```
for t in $(cat tags.txt); do git tag -f $t ${t}~1; done
```

It will process all the tags from the file.

**Update:**
In order to push the updated positions of the tags to the upstream repository, run:

```
git push --force --tags origin
```

Replace `origin` with the name(s) of all remote repositories where you want to push the tags.

Comment: It works fine ! Have you an idea to push new tags on bare repository ?

Answer (score 1):

`git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

From your screenshot I can see that you most probably used a tool that is based on `git-svn` like e. g. the nirvdrum `svn2git`, as these "tag branches" are one of the drawbacks of using `git-svn`.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want with your history, either with integrating all SVN sub-repos in one Git repo, or splitting your projects from SVN to multiple independent Git repositories.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

There are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)